# Mounting a raid1 device - no suitable drives found

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I'm having some problems with my disks; long story.. but right now I'm trying to mount a device that was part of a 2-disk raid1. For that, I tried to assemble it into a new array, but...

```
% mdadm -Av /dev/md2 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md2
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 2.
mdadm: No suitable drives found for /dev/md2
```

I was able to do a similar thing earlier, but right now it's not working with this device, and I can't figure out why.

More information:

```
% mdadm -E /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 0bf001f2:31c5e4d1:c44c77eb:7ee19756 (local to host sysresccd)
  Creation Time : Thu Mar 12 16:43:17 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
  Used Dev Size : 51199040 (48.83 GiB 52.43 GB)
     Array Size : 51199040 (48.83 GiB 52.43 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 124

    Update Time : Sat Feb 23 17:44:08 2013
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : c9e77cf6 - correct
         Events : 16015185


      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       33        2      spare   /dev/sdc1

   0     0       8       49        0      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
   2     2       8       33        2      spare   /dev/sdc1

% fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *          63   102398309    51199123+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2       102398310   110398679     4000185   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc3       110398680   976768064   433184692+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Hmm.. now I see sdc1 appears as a spare, weird.

sdd1 is the other half of the array. I was able to mount them separately earlier, and they both passed fsck and the file data was readable. When trying to put them together again, resync failed due to a bad block on sdd (in free space, I assume). I'm not sure if sdc1 has any bad blocks.

Comment: What RAID controller do you have? Also what distribution of Linux? I've found that "dmraid" works very well with my RAID1 rather than "madam".

Comment: RAID controller? This is software RAID, so the controller is mdadm. dmraid is a totally different thing. The distro is Gentoo, but I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: Well, actually I guess the kernel md / raid drivers are more suited for the title of controller.

Comment: I use software RAID too, Intel Rapid Storage. I mount it using dmraid. (well, Ubuntu does it automatically, but madam certainly isn't being used) So there is no fakeraid device, usually from your motherboard, being used in your case?

Comment: This might be a superblock not found problem (From the mdadm source code: `if (super == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, Name ": No suitable drives found for %s\n", mddev);`)

Comment: @Adambean that is probably BIOS RAID, aka "fake RAID". Not pure software RAID.

Comment: That is up for discussion. "Fake RAID" such as IRST is fully power by software. But that is not helping the OP which is using mdadm and who needs help with that.

Comment: @Hennes assuming it is a "superblock not found", how can I recover from that? I still have the other "half" of the array, but resync failed, apparently due to some bad sectors in the free space.

Comment: @Hennes fake RAID or software RAID, surely both dmraid and madam should be capable of mounting the array? I'm wondering if mounting it with dmraid works, which would be a solution to OP's problem.

Comment: Not sure. Can you add the output of the following commands to the post?  `mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1` (should print additional information about the raid member sdc1) and `fdisk -l /dev/sdc` (shows disk partition table. I am hoping to see partitions of the type *Linux RAID autodetect*). I am not sure where to take it after that, hopefully the extra information will help. If not: Is this the disk with errors or the know good one? Can you still access the other disk and thus do you have a backup? (e.g. before I suggest anything which includes the --force options).

Comment: @Adambean surely not, as they work very differently (dmraid relies on the BIOS RAID which is ultimately software too but works with a specific controller) and they also use completely different layouts and descriptors.

Comment: Agreed. On disk format can be quite different between RAID forms. Which is one of the main reasons to use mdadm.  @OP: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/69086/mdadm-superblock-recovery

Comment: I am not sure what to do with this. I really hope "Failed Devices : 1" and "Spare Devices : 1" is wrong, because the only way that makes sense if you set up a single disk mirror (!) with a hot spare. And I am pretty sure that that is an insane configuration.

Comment: @Hennes That was not my intention, but sdc1 might have become a spare when the resync failed. However, sdc1 does not currently appear at all in mdadm -D for the array that has sdd1.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `missing` in place of missing drives to activate degraded array.

```
mdadm -Av /dev/md2 /dev/sdc1 missing
```

I don't think you can easily create same array twice in the system where both are degraded.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Will list your currently active raid devices.

If the raid with `sdd1` is ok then dry:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdc1
# or
mdadm --manage /dev/md2 --re-add /dev/sdc1
```

(when /dev/md2 is the raid device with  `sdd1`)